# DFT of a function and array convolution

Tags: filters, dft, convolution

I saw some questions (and answers) on this subject, but they were all about a specific example and I'm not sure I understood.

I'm trying to understand the meaning of computing the DFT of an array representing a filter (let's say 1D).

I thought I need to think of the array (let's say [1,2,1]) as the samples of the function (signal), and just compute the DFT. But I'm not sure any more.

let's say I have:

```
cos(2pi(4x+4y)\256)
```

so it's DFT is some a at (4,4) and (-4,-4).
now I want to compute g*[1,2,1].
so I want to compute the DFT of f = [1,2,1], (by the convolution theorem).
I used the formula, but couldn't see the connection to G, the index +-(4,4) etc.

also, if f=[1,...,1] (all ones), I thought I should get 1 at F(0), and zero anywhere else. as it is a fixed function.
but this is not the case. can you explain why?

thank you!

Comment: Dont’t forget to zeropad to at least N+M+1 and center your kernel.

Comment: @Tomer I am having trouble following your question-- if the array is representing a filter- do you mean the array is the coefficients of the filter? (Then it would not be samples of the function- and then I just get confused after that with what you are trying to do. But to answer your last question, you are correct f = [all ones] will havea  constant at F(0) and zero everywhere else. That constant will be N, the number of samples in f (so if you divide by N you will get what you were expecting).